# Symfony 2 semantic bundle configuration. $configs empty in Extension class

Tags: php, symfony

I'm not having much luck trying to get a simple bundle semantic configuration example working for Symfony 2.5.2.

I'm following this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

My bundle is TetranzMyTestBundle at namespace Tetranz\MyTestBundle.

Configuration contains this from the code generator.

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('tetranz_my_test');

    // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
    // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
    // more information on that topic.

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

TetranzMyTestExtension contains this also from the code generator.

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.xml');
}
```

`app/config/config.yml` contains:

```
tetranz_my_test:
    setting1:value1
```

If I'm reading that cookbook page correctly, that should work but $configs in the load() method above contains one element which is an empty array. $config is an empty array.

I must be missing something obvious. I've tried adding some structure (Children() etc) in the Configuration class but that hasn't helped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Duh!

I didn't have a space after the colon in my config.yml. That's all it was :)